# Typescript Cannot find name 'functionName'

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I have included the typings and referenced them.
I'm not sure if the typings are correct, since I don't know how to write them. But this is what I did:

```
// This is where I'm getting Cannot find name 'Polylabel'
geometry: polylabel(feat.geometry.coordinates)
```

I have included these typings:

```
declare module "polylabel" {
/**
 * Polylabel returns the pole of inaccessibility coordinate in [x, y] format.
 * 
 * @name polylabel
 * @function
 * @param {Array<number>} polygon - Given polygon coordinates in GeoJSON-like format
 * @param {number} precision - Precision (1.0 by default)
 * @param {boolean} debug - Debugging for Console 
 * @return {Array<number>}
 * @example
 * var p = polylabel(polygon, 1.0);
 */
function polylabel(polygon: number[][][], precision?: number, debug?: boolean): number[];
namespace polylabel {}
export = polylabel;}
```

And referenced it as follow:

```
/// <reference path="globals/@types/polylabel/index.d.ts" />
```

Comment: What you are declaring should be used like polylabel.polylabel(...).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `/// <reference...` add the `.d.ts` file to your `tsconfig.json`, on the `"Files"` section.

To use this module do this:

```
import * as polylabel from 'polylabel';
polylabel.polylabel(...)
```

or (If you are using namespaces and not imports)

```
polylabel.polylabel(...)
```